# Calling Methods From Extended Classes

Tags: java, class, selenium, methods

I ask as a beginner in Java, why can't I call a method from a class that is extending that method from another class?

Example: I have class `LoginPage`, `BasePage`, and `SearchPage`.

- `BasePage` extends `LoginPage`
- `SearchPage` extends `BasePage`

So when I call the login method in SearchPage from the "LoginPage" like the following:

- `BasePage.BrowserOpen`   <-- Method from `BasePage`
- `BasePage.HomePage`      <-- Method from `BasePage`
- `BasePage.login`         <-- Method from `LoginPage`

(I am calling `login` method from the `BasePage` instead of the `LoginPage` since `BasePage` extends `LoginPage`)

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at examplesite.LoginPage.login(BasePage.java:26)
at examplesite.SearchPage.main(SearchPage.java:14)
```

I may be going about this completely wrong and if that is the case I apologize. If this is the wrong way to go about this then please tell me how I can achieve this. I do not want to copy the login method into all my scripts.

Comment: Posting the code would be helpful.

Comment: You should post the code for the login method

Comment: I think you meant to say `LoginPage extends BasePage` instead of `BasePage extends LoginPage`

Comment: @JamesWierzba no that is not true. The situation you mentioned will not compile and thus, no exceptions

Comment: Ok if that is so then I think you are misunderstanding the purpose of inheritance

Comment: @Prince Just a hint: There is nothing wrong with your extension as such. Otherwise your code would not compile. Look at what happens in  BasePage.java at line 26. Probably `login` is called on some member which you forgot to initialise in any constructor or you passed some non-initialised parameter. Anyway, as pointed out earlier: Share your code. Otherwise we cannot help you.